# Success message after submit

Tags: php

Hey now i have this but when i register only the index.php page shows up. Without the success message. When the registry is completed i redirected to index.php?msg=1 so that's in my opinion correct?

```
<?php 

if (isset($_GET['msg'] == 1)) {

echo "You have successfully registered.";

}

require_once('connect.php');

$errors = array();

if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {

if(empty($_POST['username'])){ array_push($errors, 'You did not submit a username'); }

$old_usn = mysqli_query($connect, "SELECT id FROM users WHERE name = '".htmlentities($_POST['username'], ENT_QUOTES)."' LIMIT 1;") or die(mysqli_error());
if (mysqli_num_rows($old_usn) > 0) { array_push($errors, 'This username is already registered.'); }


if (sizeof($errors) == 0) { 

$username = htmlentities($_POST['username'], ENT_QUOTES);
$email = htmlentities($_POST['email'], ENT_QUOTES);

mysqli_query($connect, "INSERT INTO users (name, hashed_pw, email, joined)
VALUES ('{$username}', '{$password1}', '{$email}', NOW());") or die ($connection_error);

header('Location: index.php?msg=1');

}

}

?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`if (isset($_GET['msg'] == 1))` that isn't the proper way to do this, since it will always be considered as being set.

You need to separate those into two conditions.

Such as:

`if (isset($_GET['msg']) && $_GET['msg'] == 1)`

I highly suggest you use a prepared statement though and `password_hash()`.

What you have now, isn't safe at all.

If you do plan on going that route (which I hope you do), then **please read over those manuals attentively** for `password_hash()` and `password_verify()`:

- http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php
- http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-verify.php

Note: You appear to have a missing variable set for `$password1`, so make sure it has value, otherwise your query will fail.

Also, `mysqli_error()` requires a database connection argument for it.

- `mysqli_error($connect)`

This line `or die ($connection_error)` will throw you an undefined variable error, least for what you posted in the question.

Comment: btw... interesting fact: `Cannot use isset() on the result of an expression (you can use "null !== expression" instead)`

Comment: @FlashThunder Thanks for that.

Comment: I'm sorry for the misunderstanding but this code isn't complete at all. But back to the point. Unfortunatly if (isset($_GET['msg']) && $_GET['msg'] == 1) doesn't work

Comment: @DutcherGames check for errors then with both the query and with error reporting.

Comment: @Fred-ii- and how do i do that? What do you mean?

Comment: @DutcherGames Place the following on top of your php file(s) just below the opening `<?php` tag --- `ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);` see if anything comes of it.

Comment: I fixed it.. I'm such a dumbass 2 hours searching and guess what.. I wrote the url wrong. I'm sorry for wasting your time and thanks for help!

Comment: @DutcherGames Those things do happen. I'm glad to know that the matter was resolved, *cheers*

Answer (score 1):

The issue is here:

```
if (isset($_GET['msg'] == 1)) {  // These are two different conditions, you have to separate them by using &
```

change it to:

```
if ( isset($_GET['msg']) && $_GET['msg'] == 1 ) {
```

and try again.

Your code is not safe at all, use prepared statement and store the `hash` password instead of plain one.

Comment: I fixed it.. I'm such a dumbass 2 hours searching and guess what.. I wrote the url wrong. I'm sorry for wasting your time and thanks for help!

Answer (score -1):

isset returns true/false. And you are comparing boolean with 1.

Comment: So what do i have to use expect isset?

Comment: use too conditions like this : if(isset($_GET['msg']) && $_GET['msg'] == 1 )

Comment: and this ?? if(isset($_GET['msg']) && $_GET['msg'] == "1" )

Comment: try to display the value of the too values : 
echo isset($_GET['msg'] . ", " . $_GET['msg'] == "1"

Comment: But it doesn't show up anything? It looks like he can't find the line

Comment: maybe your require_once('connect.php') broke your code. add a return/exit before the require_once.

Comment: I fixed it.. I'm such a dumbass 2 hours searching and guess what.. I wrote the url wrong. I'm sorry for wasting your time and thanks for help!